# dropping current row if the value of current row is the same as previous row in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

As title, I have drafted my script as below:

```
set.seed(1)
temp <- data.frame(cola=sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE),
                   stay=TRUE)
for (loop in (2:nrow(temp))) {
  temp[loop,'stay'] <- ifelse(temp[loop,'cola']==temp[loop-1,'cola'],FALSE,TRUE)    
}
temp <- temp[temp[,'stay']==TRUE,]
```

I don't like the `for-loop` there, can we somehow vectorize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can check whether the `current row`  ie. `temp$cola[-1]` is equal (`==`) to the previous row `temp$cola[-nrow(temp)]` and then concatenate (`c`) with `FALSE` to get the length same as the `nrow(temp)` and use that as an index to drop the rows.  This would also work with `characters`.

```
indx <- with(temp, c(FALSE,cola[-1]==cola[-nrow(temp)]))
temp[!indx,]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
temp <- temp[c(TRUE, diff(temp$cola) != 0),]
```